# How can I choose the values that will be represented in a drop-down list in a form in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, filter, model

I am creating an application in django and I have the next question:

I have two models which are related as I show here:

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    ident = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_in_modelB = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

class modelB(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.ForeignKey(modelA)
    ...
```

In the application, first I select the object of modelB I want to work with, and then, I show a form to select which object of modelA inside the selected modelB I want to select.

I created a form of modelB, and a drop-down list of objects of modelA appeared, but it has all the values of modelA inside the drop-down. And I want only to appear the objects that are related with the previously chosen modelA.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you mean with "previously chosen modelA", but you can provide a queryset for the form field. Assuming that `formB` is the modelform for `modelb`:

```
formB.fields['attr1'].queryset = modelA.objects.filter(...)
```

If it is not a modelform but a standard form:

```
formB.attr1.queryset = modelA.objects.filter(...)
```

Comment: And if I want to filter the queryset result with a value chosen previously? Can I send a value as a parameter to a modelform?

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean with "a value chosen previously". If this is client-side then you would need to emply some js and possibly ajax.